# Нужно ли выделять "как прежде" запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот

**Девушка не выйдет как прежде провожать.**
Как отнести "как прежде" к слову "провожать", чтобы не было ошибочного "Девушка не выйдет как прежде..."?

Comment: Не вижу проблемы. Тут к чему не "относи", смысл один. А вообще "как прежде" относится с сочетанию "выйдет провожать", так что даже умозрительной проблемы тут нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы КАК ПРЕЖДЕ отнести, как Вы хотите, только к ПРОВОЖАТЬ, а не к глаголу ВЫЙДЕТ, необходимо использовать тире.
**Д. Э. Розенталь** рекомендует:
"Тире ставится для указания места распадения простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы уточнить или подчеркнуть смысловые отношения между членами предложения. Ср.:
*а) Ходить — долго не мог;

б) Ходить долго — не мог.*
Такое тире называется интонационным, оно может отделять **любую часть предложения".**

Поэтому, учитывая Ваше желание,  предложение придётся оформлять с ТИРЕ:
***Девушка не выйдет — как прежде, провожать.***

Comment: По-моему, тире здесь излишне. "Как прежде" относится к целой конструкции "не выйдет провожать", а не отдельно к "провожать".

Comment: Согласен "Девушка не выйдет - как прежде, провожать." Иначе не подчеркнуть, что она именно провожать не выйдет, а не выйдет провожать, но как-то по-другому выйдет (хромая, подпрыгивая и т.д.) Остальные советы это однозначно не трактуют и допускают варианты толкования.

Answer (score 7):

**Как прежде** — сравнительный оборот, выделяется запятыми.
Не могу согласиться, что это предложение. Предложение "Девушка не выйдет, как прежде, провожать" — **простое, а не сложное,** осложнено сравнительным оборотом. Условий для тире тоже не вижу.

Сравните у Розенталя:
"Запятыми выделяются или отделяются сравнительные обороты с союзом **как** в следующих случаях...

4) если оборот выражен сочетаниями **как правило, как исключение, как обычно, как всегда, как прежде, как сейчас, как теперь, как нарочно** и т. п.:
Вижу, как теперь, самого хозяина (П.);
Экая досада! Как нарочно, ни души! (Т.) — в значении вводного слова;
Она теперь стала снова стройной и тонкой, как прежде (М.Г.);
День начался, как всегда, в густом тумане (Обр.);
Помню, как сейчас, эту встречу во время экспедиции..."

Answer (score 2):

***Как прежде*** надо выделять, так как это предложение с опущенным сказуемым (на это нам указывает слово ***прежде***, которое является обстоятельством, а обстоятельства зависят только от сказуемого).
*Девушка не выйдет, как (было) прежде, провожать.*

*Она, **как прежде,** захотела

Вдохнуть дыхание своё

В моё измученное тело,

В моё холодное жильё.*
А. Блок

Answer (score 1):

> Девушка не выйдет как прежде провожать. Как отнести "как прежде" к слову "провожать", чтобы не было ошибочного "Девушка не выйдет как прежде..."

Для начала, по итогам всего уже сказанного. Выделение запятыми нужно, это без вариантов. Тире может быть только интонационное (авторское), но сомнительно, чтобы оно тут было уместно.

По сути вопроса. Я не вижу причин для таких сомнений, т.е. возможности "ошибочноого" отнесения "как прежде" к "не выйдет". "Как прежде" относится ко всему предложению, но прежде всего как раз к "не выйдет". Понимание "Не выйдет провожать (как прежде), а выйдет провожать как-то по-другому" здесь совершенно невозможно, какая бы пунктуация не использовалась. Если что-то подобное имелось в виду, фразу однозначно надо переделывать.